# Use .map.js to get the whole project back

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack, node-modules

In the devtools, I found a new Host called `webpack://`. It contained all the files before it was minimized. I know that it was because of the `*.map.js` file. The thing is that it also contains all the `node_modules` too. I tried to go to the URL `webpack://` but there was nothing.

As devtools extracts the original folder with just only the use of the original file and the map.js file, How should I get the project directory with these files?

Note: I only have nodejs(npm) not any other languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow one the following guides:

1. https://pulsesecurity.co.nz/articles/javascript-from-sourcemaps
2. https://medium.com/@rarecoil/spa-source-code-recovery-by-un-webpacking-source-maps-ef830fc2351d
3. https://dev.to/xsip/automated-sourcemap-sourcecontent-extraction-by-url-40pj
4. https://gist.github.com/Ademking/a6b4c498acd03c2267700745d98923d3

Comment: hmm.. but when I visit devtools I can also see the node modules but where is it?

Comment: node modules have their own source maps which have been generated at the time of their `build` process. Your map files will contain only the code from your own project.